# On hover change another element

Tags: html, css

I want to create a hover mechanism where hovering on one div will result in changing the width of another div as below

**HTML**

```
<div id='Slider_1'></div>   
<div id='Footer_Holder'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#Slider_1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  transition: width 1s ; 
  width: 0%;
  height: 130px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#Footer_Holder {  
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

#Footer_Holder:hover + #Slider_1 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Code pen link - https://codepen.io/Volabos/pen/dyyMqzy

Surprising above code is working if I change the placements of div as below -

Can you please guide me to the right direction where I want to put `<div id='Slider_1'>` on top of `<div id='Footer_Holder'></div>`

Comment: One solution would be to get your CSS selector working (i.e. put `Slider_1` after the `Footer_holder` div) and position them with another CSS style.

Answer (score 1):

Well the "+" selector works only if you switch your divs position:

```
<div id='Footer_Holder'></div>
<div id='Slider_1'></div>
```

Here read all about the selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp